In VB.NET what does it mean to declare a Byte array as New Byte(-1){}
I am trying to understand some VB code that does this:
Public Function Foo( ByVal a as Byte(), ByVal b as Byte(), ByVal Optional c as Byte() = Nothing) as Byte()

  
  <snip>

  c = If(c, New Byte(-1) {} )

  <snip>

End Function

What does it mean to use -1 there?  When I  use a translator to convert the code to C#, it doesn't like  -1 and throws an error that it's out of range and must be non-negative.

In VB.NET, you create an array by specifying the upper bound, e.g.
Dim arr = New Byte(99) {}

creates an array with a Length of 100. If the upper bound is 1 less than the Length and you specify -1 as the upper bound, what's the Length? It's zero, i.e. you created an empty array. Since .NET Framework 4.6, you should be using the Array.Empty method to do that:
c = If(c, Array.Empty(Of Byte)())

c = c ?? Array.Empty<byte>();

I think that C# would also support this:
c ??= Array.Empty<byte>();


I thought New Byte(100) would create 100 slots that might be referenced zero-based as b[0] through b[99] but I never expected the size declaration to work like that!

@Tim, I think it may have been done that way for compatibility with VB6. I haven't looked at this for quite some time but, if I remember correctly, VB6 arrays are 1-based rather than 0-based, so the length and upper bound are the same value. If you created an array in VB6 using 100 then you'd expect to be able to access elements up to index 100. If VB.NET used the length rather than the upper bound, VB.NET code that specified 100 when creating an array would only be able to access elements up to 99, so upgraded VB6 code that expected an index 100 would fail.

New Byte(-1) instantiates a new byte array with zero elements in it. If C comes in as Nothing, then C will be set to a Byte array with zero elements (for example, C.Count = 0).
